# how to set an image when a segmented control is selected and one for unselected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have 3 segmented controls and I want to use one image for when the first segmented control is selected and one for when it is unselected... do the same for the other two segmented controls but obviously use different images. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Add action to your segmented Control.

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Then implemented `segmentedControlClicked:` .

```
-(void) segmentedControlClicked:(UISegmentedControl*) segmentedControl
{
    if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    { 
        NSLog(@"First selected");
    }
    else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
         NSLog(@"Secondselected");
    }
    else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
    {
         NSLog(@"third selected"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: On this code, where am I supposed to place the image of the segmented controls that I want to use. Sorry I didnt' get it very well.

Comment: @Jovany : put your images in appropriate `if else` blocks .

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this a while back for a similar problem. Maybe you can reuse some of it.

```
// Create a segmented control.
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:nil];
[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up_button.png"] atIndex:0 animated:YES];
[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down_button.png"] atIndex:1 animated:YES];
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 30);
[segmentedControl setMomentary:YES];
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

// Check if this is the first and / or the last page in order to enable or disable the back / forward button.
if ([recipesArray count] == 1) {
    [segmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [segmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:1];
} else if ([currentIndex intValue] == 0) {
    [segmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];
} else if ([currentIndex intValue]+1 == [recipesArray count]) {
    [segmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:1];
}

// Initialize a bar button item with the segmented control as custom view and assign it to the right bar button item.
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;

[segmentedControl release];
```